# Preserve history between sessions of terminal usage (Mac osx)

Tags: macos, terminal

I followed a different guide: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50649/how-to-make-bash-terminal-app-remember-history-of-previous-sessions

and called the three commands:

```
sudo -iu root
cd ~(myusername)
chown (myusername) .bash_history
```

But now upon every start of terminal I get the following output:

```
Last login: Thu Apr 21 15:39:19 on ttys000
-bash: USERNAME: No such file or directory
```

and I am still unable to retrieve recent commands in my history using the up-arrow key. I know I shouldn't have executed commands I didn't know the meaning of. Can anyone point me in the right direction to put my terminal back into place and also help preserve history upon closing terminal?

Answer (score 0):

What were the exact commands that you typed?  I mean, presumably you did substitute your name for (myusername) didn't you?  And the command

```
cd ~(myusername)
```

makes no sense to me.  On its own,

```
cd ~
```

will take you to your home directory.

Okay.  Basic troubleshooting (put your answers up here).  Load up terminal and type (note that there's no need to use sudo for any of this):

```
cd ~ # changes to your home directory
ls -la .bash_history # checks the permissions and ownership of your bash_history
```

Your bash history should have the following permissions (or similar):

```
-rw-------@ 1 headbanger  staff  10619 20 Apr 17:08 .bash_history
```

So, for me to fix this for my account, I'd type:

```
chown headbanger:staff .bash_history # if you aren't the owner, it will be necessary to use sudo here.
chmod "u+rw,go-rwx" .bash_history # greybeards will use Octal 600 for this
```

I've avoided using octal for chmod to make this more readable.  The letters in chmod mean the following:

```
u User
g Group
o Other
a All (u,g & o)

- Remove permission
+ Add permission
= Set permission

r Read
w Write
x Execute
```

Let us know how you get on!

Comment: So for your first comment I used cd ~akashkakumani
      Then I followed your advice for the rest replacing headbanger with akashkakumani but when I restarted my terminal I was still left with:

Comment: Last login: Sat Apr 23 16:22:47 on ttys000
-bash: USERNAME: No such file or directory
wireless1x-155-41-93-240:~ akashkakumani$

Comment: It's a minor point - but 'cd ~akashkakumani' and 'cd ~' will do the same thing.  Please can you show the result of 'ls -la .bash_history'